# What does the CLF number of CoAx Cable mean?

Tags: rf, antenna

Specifically, I want to connect a 900MHz antenna using (~.5m) a cable - does the CLF number of the CoAx that I use matter?

What should it be? (Or how would I calculate it?)

What does CLF even stand for?

Comment: Seems to be the limit in the current that the fuse built in the cable can sustain without burning.

Comment: @clabacchio, I dont think so, it seems to be related loosely to capacitive line loss. I use loosely because finding a reputable source for this is nearly impossible and I have never hear of use of the term [CLF](http://abbreviations.yourdictionary.com/clf) for a coax. It seems they have capacitive loss factor.

Comment: @Kortuk but I've googled and found many vendors selling CLF-100, CLF-200 coaxial cables...

Comment: @clabacchio, yes, and that seems to relate to your line loss on the cable. For example this sites the line loss as: [Low Loss CLF100](http://www.cclonline.com/product/53861/LM242/Wireless-Accessories/LM-Technologies-Square-Magnetic-Antenna-SMA-Base-Mount-with-1-5m-Cable/NET1625/).

Comment: @Kortuk I admit my lacks in this topic, what I've found is that explanation for the acronym, and whén I've looked for coax and limit fuse, I've found some coax that have a fuse line between the core and the shield. But your suggestion is more likely (in the link is associated with IEEE so...).

Comment: @clabacchio, it is not a term I have ever used and most sites really do seem to use it and not give me a line loss per meter at all. So unless someone digs up a spec which was outside my google fu, I have to label it marketing.

Comment: @clabacchio Does CLF really stand for capacitive loss factor? That phrase gets no google hits...

Comment: @Autopulated ask Kortuck, I haven't been luckier than you googling it...but he knows better the topic

Comment: For what it means, I've found some hits for the [CLF](http://www.acronymattic.com/CLF.html) acronym: the most likely is Capacitive Loss Factor, as @Kortuk said

Comment: I can hardly believe that engineering facts are different in your country than here. After many years of my practice with tv antennas and cables (i.e. 0-2GHz), I swear I never heard CLF term. I bet it is just some local marketing name or something.

Comment: @AlKepp It seems to not be regional but another marketing ploy. I have seen many many things that are just marketing. It is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to take into account cable losses in your signal, but over 0.5m your loss should be relatively small. As you look at cabling take into account the dB loss per meter and use that to determine how much power you are losing each way. CLF seems to be a way to avoid specifying a value most places I can find.

It stinks of marketing to me.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the type of cable or the antenna. Cable loss is part of the overall system performance,  you need to take into account amplifier power output, coax losses, any gain from the antenna, and the local terrain to get an idea of how the system will perform. Typically coax losses are specified in dB per 100 feet. Transmitting at 900 MHz really won't be the challenge,  it'll be receiving.  If you can determine the received signal strength at the antenna that's also a good number to know. Coax losses is symmetrical, meaning if there's 3 dB of loss in the coax, you'll loose half the transmit and receive power.

At 900Mhz though, it should be easy enough to overcome any coax losses through .5 meter of coax with a suitable antenna that has more gain than losses in the coax. Hopefully this will help in your decision on what type of feedline to use in your application.  I've never heard the term CLF before, I think @Kortuk is correct on the marketing.

Comment: Sorry I missed this answer before, it is a good one. Hope you keep answering questions!

Answer (score 1):

The 50 Ohm code is more important.
Please read this to learn about this cable and other stuff.

http://sharon.esrac.ele.tue.nl/~on9cvd/E-Waarom%2050%20Ohm.htm

Quote: "The selection of 50 Ohm for coaxial cable may therefore be regarded as an optimal value between the optimization for minimal loss and maximum power transport capabilities"